# Php no output only a blank page

Tags: php

Hello guys I need some help. Yesterday, my php codes works fine there's no error and have an output displayed in the browser. And this morning after running my new php code, the Firefox browser was a blank page only. So I've tried my other php files that works yesterday and they don't have an output. I can't figured out the problem. I can't post the screenshot of my works because I need 10 reputations to post an image. I'm new here in stack overflow I hope you can help me. By the way I'm using xampp. Thanks

```
<?php
    $day = "Tuesday";
    $date = 31;
    $year = 2017;
    echo "Today is " .$day." ".$date." ".$year."!";
?>
```

Comment: Read error logs.

Comment: So you can post the code itself?

Comment: What server are you running? Are you using a web hosting service or a server you have on your PC?

Comment: *I can't post the screenshot of my works because I need 10 reputations to post an image* You should not post screenshots but describe as good as possible the issue with the code where the error(s) occured

Comment: These are my codes yesterday and this code have an output also.
<?php
$day = "Tuesday";
$date = 31;
$year = 2017;
echo "Today is " .$day." ".$date." ".$year."!";
?>
All of my php codes that created has no output.

Comment: Post error log. Its location depends on what web server you are using. Google `php error log <the name of your server>`. HTTP server is typically Apache, Nginx or IIS.

Comment: I'm using xampp.

Comment: @JohnUbar To find the error logs browse to your xampp installation folder for example: `C:\xampp\apache\logs`

Comment: [Wed Mar 08 16:12:34.793119 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 11184:tid 168] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Mar 08 16:12:34.955851 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 11184:tid 168] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Mar 08 16:12:34.994859 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11184:tid 168] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Comment: What is the path to your file, and how do you open it in your browser?

Comment: @Bartosz Zasada C:\xampp\htdocs\php\echo.php. I browse the file then I right-click the echo.php file and then select open with firefox browser.

Comment: That's not how you open files in browser if you want them parsed by PHP. Open http://localhost/php/echo.php in you browser. Check out https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html for more basic instructions, this one will be explained under "Where should I place my web content?".

Comment: @Bartosz Zasada Thank you sir you save my life! All of my php file have already an output. And thanks also to everyone who replied God bless! :D

Comment: please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12772851#12772851  to resolve issues with the "white screen of death"